# Can i use ROOT name as my web app name in tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat8

I have deployed war file file in tomcat and deleted the ROOT filder inside webapps folder.I renamed my war file into ROOT.Now we are able to access our application on server.But what my question is, Can i rename my web app as ROOT?Is it causes any problems in future on my production server?Please tell me,For all help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely fine. You can rename the ROOT to some other war file name. I have my application deployed in production (Tomcat 8) without the ROOT folder. You shouldn't get any problem.

Please refer the below link (Section Naming).

[image]

[Tomcat naming](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: Ok.Please tell me  why web app name path is added to static files path if both are placed in webapps folder.

Comment: The static file path is required because you can set the context folder to any location. For example, I have my context path set as "../applicationName/web" which is outside webapps folder. What you mention in appBase is the pathname of a directory that may contain web applications to be deployed on this virtual host. If not specified, the default of webapps will be used (i.e. if you don't mention anything in the context path inside Host tag in server.xml).

Comment: <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

Comment: I mentioned like this.What i have to do for removing webapp name from my static files path.